# Early parsing Bash options before getopt

Tags: bash

I use getopt to do the actual parsing of command line options later on, but I want to enable some flags early if their options are present. I'm trying to parse them with a regex at the beginning of my script:

This is what I've got at the moment, but it's not working. I can't seem to find any examples of anyone else doing this (probably a reason, not sure what it is):

```
# Enable extended pattern matching features.
shopt -s extglob

# Internal values & flag initialization.
declare -A __
__[OPT]="$@"                        # the command line options
__[PWD]=$(pwd)                      # the current directory
__[SRC]="$BASH_SOURCE"              # unresolved path to executable
__[SRC_DIR]=$(dirname ${__[SRC]})   # parent directory of unresolved executable
__[BIN]=$(readlink -f "$0")         # resolved path to executable
__[BIN_DIR]=$(dirname ${__[BIN]})   # parent directory of resolved executable

# Preparse option string to enable flags early.
[[ ${__[OPT]} =~ (-d\b)|(--debug\b) ]] &&  __[DEBUG]=true || __[DEBUG]=false
[[ ${__[OPT]} =~ (-v\b)|(--verbose\b) ]] &&  __[VERBOSE]=true || __[VERBOSE]=false


for key in "${!__[@]}"; do
   echo "$key: ${__[$key]}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

`\b` is not recognized as a word-boundary marker by the `=~` operator. Just use a space instead (since spaces will separate options in `${__[OPT]}` anyway).

```
[[ ${__[OPT]} =~ (-d\ )|(--debug\ ) ]] && ...
```

Comment: While using a space instead is good advice, it _depends on the platform_ (unfortunately) whether `=~` recognizes `\b` . The picture is muddled by a bug in bash 4.x with respect to regex _literals_; use an intermediate variable to test: try `re='a\b'; [[ 'a ' =~ $re ]] && echo YES`; on Linux, it'll succeed; by contrast, it won't work on OSX (you'd have to use `re='a[[:>:]]'`).

Comment: I initially tried using a space, however when the flag is at the end of the option string (i.e.: "bish -d") it is not matched.

Comment: Thank you for the information about the bash 4.x bug, that appears to have been the issue.